# How to do multiple Match statements, or join two queries with the same keyname

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A user can be friends with another user. A user can also follow a users profile page. I want to query on all friends and followed_users (users who own the followed profile page)

This return the followed_users

```
match (user:User {id: SOME_ID})
-[:FOLLOWED_PAGE]->(Page)<-[:PROFILE_PAGE]-(followed_user:User)
return followed_user
```

This return the friend

```
match (u:User {uuid: SOME_ID})-[:CONNECTED_USER]->(friend:User)
return friend
```

This will union both

```
match (user:User {id: SOME_ID})
-[:FOLLOWED_PAGE]->(Page)<-[:PROFILE_PAGE]-(followed_user:User)
return followed_user
UNION ALL match (u:User {uuid: SOME_ID})-[:CONNECTED_USER]->(friend:User)
return friend
```

The problem is, I want to keep querying. Union will return.

This is what I WANT to do, but it doesnt work (the second match overwrites the first one)

```
match (user:User {id: SOME_ID})
-[:FOLLOWED_PAGE]->(Page)<-[:PROFILE_PAGE]-(friend:User)
match (user)-[:CONNECTED_USER]->(friend:User)
WHERE (page:Page)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(friend)
return page
```

How can I do something like this?

EDIT: Stefan Armbruster

Initial setup query:

```
create (PP:Page {title: "Jim"}), (Jim:User {name: "Jim"}), (You:User {name: "You"}), (Frank:User {name: "Frank"}), (Jimpost:Post {title: "Jim posted this, You follow his page"}), (Frankpost:Post {title: "Frank posted this, You are his friend (connected_to)"}),
(You)-[:CONNECTED_USER]->(Frank),
(Frank)-[:CONNECTED_USER]->(You),
(You)-[:BOOKMARKED_PAGE]->(PP),
(PP)<-[:PROFILE_PAGE]-(Jim),
(Jimpost)<-[:POSTED]-(Jim),
(Frankpost)<-[:POSTED]-(Frank)
```

You are "You". Frank is your "Friend" (CONNECTED_USER). You bookmarked "Jim"'s ProfilePage (Page). So I would like to be able to query using both "Friends" and "Followed" (Users whos profile pages a user has bookmarked) users. In this instance they have both posted a page, but the use case is not unique to just posted pages

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the comma `,` to create composite patterns:

```
match (user:User {id: SOME_ID})-[:FOLLOWED_PAGE]->(Page)<-[:PROFILE_PAGE]-(friend:User),
      (user)-[:CONNECTED_USER]->(friend:User),
      (page:Page)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(friend)
return page
```

The comma basically build up one single pattern. The separate parts are connected by commonly used identifiers (here `user, page, friend`).

Comment: The individual querys work, but together, no rows are returned ```(user:User {id: SOME_ID})-[:FOLLOWED_PAGE]->(Page)<-[:PROFILE_PAGE]-(friend:User)``` <- works. ```(user:User {id: ID})-[:CONNECTED_USER]->(friend:User)``` <- works. But adding them with a comma returns no rows. For now I an just returning "friend". Each query returns 1 friend. The join query returns none (I was hoping for 2)

Comment: Very cool tool. I can't get the link to work, it keeps resetting to Matrix. I will make an edit at the bottom of my post with the initial query and a quick explanation. Thanks @Stefan Armbruster